# "Lock wait timeout exceeded" when sending data from Google Sheets to MySQL

Tags: mysql, jdbc, google-apps-script, google-sheets-macros

I wrote an Apps Script macro to send data from a Google spreadsheet to a MySQL table. In a first time, in delete some rows in the table and then I add rows in this table. I sometimes get a "Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction" error. Sometimes it runs after 100 seconds, sometimes 4 minutes.

I don't understand what is wrong with this code.

```js
//classeur.insertSheet("feuillebis")
//feuillebis=classeur.getSheets()[1]
//var feuillebis=classeur.getSheetByName('feuillebis')
var classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() ;
var feuille = classeur.getActiveSheet();
var host = "107.167.186.180";
var databaseName = "eatology";
var userName = "root";
var password = "eatology";
var port = 3306;
var tableName = "weekly_order";

var url = 'jdbc:mysql://' + host + ':' + port + '/' + databaseName;
var nbrow = feuille.getMaxRows()

function Send_Weekly_Order_To_Data_Base() {
  ///here are all the connection parameters
  var classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var feuille = classeur.getActiveSheet();
  var nbrow = feuille.getMaxRows();
  var host = "107.167.186.180";
  var databaseName = "eatology";
  var userName = "root";
  var password = "eatology";
  var port = 3306;
  var tableName = "weekly_order";
  var url = 'jdbc:mysql://' + host + ':' + port + '/' + databaseName;
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, userName, password); 
  conn.setAutoCommit(false);
  
  ///get the weekly_order as an array from the sql
  var rowcount = 0;
  var stmt2 = conn.createStatement();
  var results = stmt2.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM eatology.weekly_order");
  while (results.next()) {
    if (results.getInt(1) > rowcount){
      rowcount = results.getInt(1)
    }
  }
  conn.commit();
  results.close();
  stmt2.close();
  
  ///delete the rows from the current week where we are running the macro
  var timezone1 = classeur.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
  var date1 = Utilities.formatDate(feuille.getRange(2, 2).getValue(), timezone1, "yyyy-MM-dd");
  var date2 = Utilities.formatDate(feuille.getRange(2, 3).getValue(), timezone1, "yyyy-MM-dd");
  var date3 = Utilities.formatDate(feuille.getRange(2, 4).getValue(), timezone1, "yyyy-MM-dd");
  var date4 = Utilities.formatDate(feuille.getRange(2, 5).getValue(), timezone1, "yyyy-MM-dd");
  var date5 = Utilities.formatDate(feuille.getRange(2, 6).getValue(), timezone1, "yyyy-MM-dd");
  var date6 = Utilities.formatDate(feuille.getRange(2, 7).getValue(), timezone1, "yyyy-MM-dd");
  
  ///clear the table weekly-order in the database
  var stmt1 = conn.createStatement();
  var result = stmt1.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM eatology.weekly_order where `Date` = "  + "'" + date1 + "'" +" or `Date` = " + "'" + date2 + "'" +" or `Date` = " + "'" + date3 + "'" +" or `Date` = "+  "'" + date4 + "'" +" or `Date` = " + "'" + date5 + "'" +" or `Date` = "+ "'" + date6 + "'" );
  //var result = stmt1.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM eatology.weekly_order where `Date` = "  + "'" + date1 +"'");
 
  conn.commit();
  stmt1.close();
  conn.close();
  
  rowcount = rowcount + 1;
  
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, userName, password); 
  conn.setAutoCommit(false);
  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement('INSERT INTO eatology.weekly_order '
      + '(`Uid`, `Date`, `MP`, `Cname`, `Pname`, `Breakfast`, `Snack1`, `Lunch`, `Snack2`, `Dinner`) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)');
  
  var program_name_line = 0;
  var array = feuille.getRange(1, 1, nbrow, 7).getValues();
  for (var j = 1; j < 7; j = j + 1) {
    var inside = 0;
    var i = 1;
    while (array[i][0] != "Total" && i < 1000) {
      i = i + 1
      var color = feuille.getRange(i + 1, j + 1).getBackgrounds()
      var fi1 = array[i][0].toString();
      var fij = array[i][j].toString();
      var empty = (fij == "");
      var already = 0;
      var test11111 = (color != "#5d31ce");
      
      var cas1 = ((empty == false) && (fi1 != "Total") && (inside == 0));
      var cas2 = (color == "#5d31ce" && inside == 1);
      var cas3 = (empty == false);
      
      if ((fi1 != "Total") && (inside == 0) && color != "#5d31ce") {
        program_name_line = i;
        inside = 1; 
        
        if (empty == false) {
          var Uid = rowcount;
          var Date1 = (Utilities.formatDate(array[1][j], timezone1, "yyyy-MM-dd"));   
          var MP = (array[program_name_line][0]);
          var place = ((fij).indexOf("-"));
          var length = (fij.length);
          var Pname = ((fij).substring(place + 1, length));
          var Cname = ((fij).substring(0, place));
          var list = (meal(MP, Pname));
          var Breakfast = list[0];
          var Snack1 = list[1];
          var Lunch = list[2];
          var Snack2 = list[3];
          var Dinner = list[4];
          if (MP == "TM") {
            var Breakfast = 1;
            var Snack1 = 1;
            var Lunch = 1;
            var Snack2 = 1;
            var Dinner = 1;
          }
          rowcount = rowcount + 1;
          stmt.setInt(1, Uid);
          stmt.setString(2, Date1);
          stmt.setString(3, MP);
          stmt.setString(4, Cname);
          stmt.setString(5, Pname);
          stmt.setInt(6, Breakfast);
          stmt.setInt(7, Snack1);
          stmt.setInt(8, Lunch);
          stmt.setInt(9, Snack2);
          stmt.setInt(10, Dinner);
          stmt.addBatch();
        }
      }
      else if (color == "#5d31ce" && inside == 1) {
        inside = 0;
      }
      else if (empty == false && color != "#5d31ce") {
        var Uid = rowcount ;
        var Date1 = (Utilities.formatDate(array[1][j], timezone1, "yyyy-MM-dd"));
        var MP =  (array[program_name_line][0].toString());
        var place = ((fij).indexOf("-"));
        var length =  (fij.length);
        var Pname = ((fij).substring(place + 1, length));
        var Cname = ((fij).substring(0, place));
        var list = (meal(MP, Pname));
        var Breakfast = (list[0]);
        var Snack1 = (list[1]);
        var Lunch = (list[2]);
        var Snack2 = (list[3]);
        var Dinner = (list[4]);
        
        if (MP == "TM") {
          var Breakfast = 1;
          var Snack1 = 1;
          var Lunch = 1;
          var Snack2 = 1;
          var Dinner = 1;
        }
        
        rowcount = rowcount+1;
        stmt.setInt(1, Uid);
        stmt.setString(2, Date1);
        stmt.setString(3, MP);
        stmt.setString(4, Cname);
        stmt.setString(5, Pname);
        stmt.setInt(6, Breakfast);
        stmt.setInt(7, Snack1);
        stmt.setInt(8, Lunch);
        stmt.setInt(9, Snack2);
        stmt.setInt(10, Dinner);
        stmt.addBatch(); 
      }
    }
  }
  
  stmt.executeBatch();
  conn.commit();
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
}

function meal(MP, Pname){
  var result= [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  //in order to know if we have two snacks or only one because if the programm has more than 1200 cal, there are two snacks, otherwise, only one snack
  var two_snacks = 1
  if (MP.indexOf("1200") > -1) {
    two_snacks = 0
  }
  //if the program type is '3'
  if (Pname.indexOf("3") > -1) {
    result[0] = 1;
    result[1] = 1;
    result[2] = 1;
    result[4] = 1;
    if (two_snacks == 1) {
      result[3] = 1;
    }
  }
  //if the program type is '2'
  if (Pname.indexOf("2") > -1 && Pname.indexOf("S") == -1) {
    result[0] = 1;
    result[1] = 1;
    result[2] = 1;
    if (two_snacks == 1) {
      result[3] = 1;
    }
  }
  //if there is the B letter
  if (Pname.indexOf("B") > -1) {
    result[0] = 1;
  }
  //if there is the L letter
  if (Pname.indexOf("L") > -1) {
    result[2] = 1;
  }
  //if there is the D letter
  if (Pname.indexOf("D") > -1) {
    result[4] = 1;
  }
  //if there is the 2S letter
  if (Pname.indexOf("2S") > -1) {
    result[1] = 1;
    result[3] = 1;
  }
  //if there is the 1S letter
  if (Pname.indexOf("1S") > -1) {
    result[1] = 1;
    result[1] = 1;
  }
  return result
}
```

Comment: You should clarify the source of the error (MySQL, Apps Script), and the size of the batch if relevant.

Comment: @descours Hi. I'm looking at older questions that don't seem to have been resolved. How did you get on? Did you resolve your problem, or are you still looking for help?